# What's the difference between "Hash.new(0)" and "{}"

Tags: ruby, hash, constructor

I was getting an unexpected (to me) behavior in my code so I tried to isolate the problem in the REPL.  However these constructors both appear to have the same result (an empty hash):

```
irb> a = {}
# => {}

irb> b = Hash.new(0)
# => {}
```

When I pass `{}` into a reduce function I get a NoMethodError, though.  What is the difference between these two constructors?

```
irb> arr = "count the occurance of each of the words".scan(/\w+/)
# => ["count", "the", "occurance", "of", "each", "of", "the", "words"]

irb> x = arr.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |hsh, word| hsh[word] += 1; hsh }
# => {"count"=>1, "the"=>2, "occurance"=>1, "of"=>2, "each"=>1, "words"=>1}

irb> x = arr.reduce({}) { |hsh, word| hsh[word] += 1; hsh }
# NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: [Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) isn't clear on this? "If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default values."

Comment: Downvote?  That's a legit question.  I'm 3 days into Ruby (and it's documentation) and no, I didn't find it immediately clear from the documentation.

Comment: Even with the examples?

Comment: Even so. Actually, earlier I assumed that there was some self-evident documentation I had missed, but looking more closely now I don't see where the `{}` constructor pattern is described or compared to `.new()`.  Where is that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Hash.new(0)` sets default value for any key to `0`, while `{}` sets `nil`

```
h1 = Hash.new(0)
h1.default  # => 0
h1[:a] += 1 # => 1
h2 = {}
h2.default  # => nil
h2[:a] += 1 # => NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Is the difference in the constructor or that `Hash.new(0)` is passing a zero?  Or in other words, are `Hash.new()` and `{}` equivalent?

Comment: @doub1ejack `Hash.new()` equivalent to `{}`

Answer (score 0):

If we create a hash object using Hash.new(0), the parameter, 0 in this case, will be used as the hash’s default value—it will be the value returned if you look up a key that isn’t yet in the hash

```
def count_frequency(word_list)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  word_list.each { |word|
    counts[word] += 1
  }
   counts
end
p count_frequency(%w(red blue green red white black))
```

will produce

```
{"red"=>2, "blue"=>1, "green"=>1, "white"=>1, "black"=>1}
```

Adding more to it

```
brands= Hash.new( "nike" )
puts "#{brands[0]}"
puts "#{brands[101]}"
```

both will produce

```
nike
nike
```

and

```
brands = {0 => "nike" , 1 =>"Reebok"}
brands[0]   # => "nike"
brands[1]   # => "Reebok"
brands[100] # => nil
```