# Working with Hashes that have a default value

Tags: ruby, default, new-operator, ruby-hash

Am learning to code with ruby. I am learning about hashes and i dont understand this code: `count = Hash.new(0)`. It says that the 0 is a default value, but when i run it on irb it gives me an empty hash {}. If 0 is a default value why can't i see something like `count ={0=>0}`. Or is the zero an accumulator but doesn't go to the keys or values? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0 will be the fallback if you try to access a key in the hash that doesn't exist

For example:

`count = Hash.new` -> `count['key'] => nil`

vs

`count = Hash.new(0)` -> `count['key'] => 0`

Comment: Might want to answer this part too: *"Or is the zero an accumulator but doesn't go to the keys or values?"* as it is an excellent question and inadvertently identifies a common ruby gotcha

Comment: @engineersmnky can you rephrase what you interpret OP is asking? I didn't understand what he meant by asking if it was "an accumulator" / what the common ruby gotcha was

Comment: @melcher There are two common gotchas with Hash defaults: (1) accidentally shared references with things like `Hash.new([])` so `h = Hash.new([]); h[:v].push(11)` has side effects; (2) no auto-vivification with `Hash.new(some_value)` so `h = Hash.new(0); puts h[:v]` gives you `0` but doesn't add `:v` as a key but it would if you started with `h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }`. Not sure which one is meant though.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, I'm writing an answer to address those gotchas since I think it's worth repeating for a question like this, i just didn't really understand what was meant by 'accumulator'.... is that a reference to something like `inject`'s arguments?

Comment: This answer is not especially useful as it casts no light on the question, "When should hashes be created with the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument and no block?".

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the answer from @jeremy-ramos and comment from @mu-is-too-short.

There are two common gotcha's with defaulting hash values in this way.

### 1. Accidentally shared references.

Ruby uses the **exact same** object in memory that you pass in as the default value for every missed key.

For an immutable object (like `0`), there is no problem. However you might want to write code like:

```rb
hash = Hash.new([])
hash[key] << value
```

or

```rb
hash = Hash.new({})
hash[key][second_key] = value
```

This will not do what you'd expect. Instead of `hash[unknown_key]` returning a new, empty array or hash it will return the exact same array/hash object for every key.

so doing:

```rb
hash = Hash.new([])
hash[key1] << value1
hash[key2] << value2
```

results in a hash where `key1` and `key2` both point to the same array object containing `[value1, value2]`

See [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795510/when-is-a-block-or-object-that-is-passed-to-hash-new-created-or-run?rq=1)

#### Solution

To solve this you can create a hash with a default block argument instead (which is called whenever a missing key is accessed and lets you assign a value to the missed key)

```
hash = Hash.new{|h, key| h[key] = [] }
```

### 2. Assignment of missed keys with default values

When you access a missing key that returns the default value, you might expect that the hash will now contain that key with the value returned. It does not. Ruby does not modify the hash, it simply returns the default value. So, for example:

```rb
hash = Hash.new(0) #$> {} 
hash.keys.empty? #$> true
hash[:foo] #$> 0
hash[:foo] == 0 #$> true
hash #$> {}
hash.keys.empty? #$> true
```

#### Solution

This confusion is also addressed using the block approach, where they keys value can be explicitly set.

Comment: This is exactly where I was going with my comment under @jeremyramos's answer. The question in the OP was very insightful (whether or not it was intended to be) and I thought it deserved adequate attention.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) docs are not very clear on this. I hope that the example below clarifies the difference and one of the frequent uses of `Hash.new(0)`.

The first chunk of code uses `Hash.new(0)`. The hash has a default value of 0, and when new keys are encountered, their value is 0. This method can be used to count the characters in the array.

The second chunk of code fails, because the default value for the key (when not assigned) is `nil`. This value cannot be used in addition (when counting), and generates an error.

```
count = Hash.new(0)

puts "count=#{count}"
# count={}

%w[a b b c c c].each do |char|
  count[char] += 1
end

puts "count=#{count}"
# count={"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}


count = Hash.new

puts "count=#{count}"

%w[a b b c c c].each do |char|
  count[char] += 1
  # Fails: in `block in <main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
end

puts "count=#{count}"
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[What's the difference between "Hash.new(0)" and "{}"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35177845/967621)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR When you initialize hash using [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) you can setup default value or default proc (the value that would be returned if given key does not exist)

Regarding the question to understand this magic firstly you need to know that Ruby hashes have default values. To access default value you can use [`Hash#default`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default) method

This default value by default :) is `nil`

```
hash = {}

hash.default # => nil

hash[:key] # => nil
```

You can set default value with [`Hash#default=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D)

```
hash = {}

hash.default = :some_value

hash[:key] # => :some_value
```

Very important note: it is dangerous to use mutable object as default because of side effect like this:

```
hash = {}
hash.default = []

hash[:key] # => []

hash[:other_key] << :some_item # will mutate default value

hash[:key] # => [:some_value]
hash.default # => [:some_value]

hash # => {}
```

To avoid this you can use [`Hash#default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) and [`Hash#default_proc=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) methods

```
hash = {}

hash.default_proc # => nil

hash.default_proc = proc { [] }

hash[:key] # => []

hash[:other_key] << :some_item # will not mutate default value
hash[:other_key] # => [] # because there is no this key

hash[:other_key] = [:symbol]
hash[:other_key] << :some_item
hash[:other_key] # => [:symbol, :some_item]

hash[:key] # => [] # still empty array as default
```

Setting `default` cancels `default_proc` and vice versa

```
hash = {}

hash.default = :default

hash.default_proc = proc { :default_proc }

hash[:key] # => :default_proc

hash.default = :default

hash[:key] # => :default

hash.default_proc # => nil
```

Going back to `Hash.new`

When you pass argument to this method, you initialize default value

```
hash = Hash.new(0)

hash.default # => 0
hash.default_proc # => nil
```

When you pass block to this method, you initialize default proc

```
hash = Hash.new { 0 }

hash.default # => nil
hash[:key] # => 0
```